# Not all form fields are reaching model during save

Tags: python, django

I'm sending an image field with crop dimensions to django in order to edit the image before saving. The edit and save part are working, but only when I hardcode the required dimensions.

My problem is that in the model the cropping dimensions don't turn up and show as None.

The model being saved is processed using a formset.

The cropping dimensions were added later, I've not forgotten to migrate the fields.

Here's my code:

**view.py**

```
for i, form in enumerate(picture_formset_from_request.forms):
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

From pycharm this would appear to be the file where the data is not passed any further:

**forms/models.py**

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Save this form's self.instance object if commit=True. Otherwise, add
    a save_m2m() method to the form which can be called after the instance
    is saved manually at a later time. Return the model instance.
    """
    if self.errors:
        raise ValueError(
            "The %s could not be %s because the data didn't validate." % (
                self.instance._meta.object_name,
                'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
            )
        )
    if commit:
        # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
        self.instance.save() # <- it seems to go wrong here
        self._save_m2m()
    else:
        # If not committing, add a method to the form to allow deferred
        # saving of m2m data.
        self.save_m2m = self._save_m2m
    return self.instance

save.alters_data = True
```

On line self.instance.save() the required data is present within 'cleanded_data', but within 'instance' the x, y, w, h all show as None.

x, y, w, h were added later in an attempt to crop the photos before saving down.

**models.py**

```
class LetterPicture(models.Model):
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Letter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slot = models.IntegerField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="letter_pictures/%Y/%m/%d", default="empty.jpg")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    x = models.FloatField(null=True)
    y = models.FloatField(null=True)
    w = models.FloatField(null=True)
    h = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_image( # <- data not available here
            desired_width=200,
            desired_height=200
        )

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LetterPictureModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    picture = forms.ImageField(
        label='Picture',
        widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Picture'
        })
    )
    x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    w = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    h = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = LetterPicture
        fields = ['picture', 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h', ]
        widgets = {
            'letter': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'slot': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'x': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'y': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'w': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'h': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

I'm only 4 weeks into Django - so my understanding of what exactly I'm doing isn't quite up to scratch.

What's stopping the x, y, w, h fields from reaching the model during save?

Comment: Are you overriding `save` method in your `ModelForm` class?

Comment: @xyres I had been, but not since adopting the approach of adjusting images within the model. I've added my forms.py for this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what the problem was, but this was a successful work around that doesn't feel too hacky:

```
if form.is_valid():
    letter_picture_pre_save = form.save(commit=False)
    letter_picture_pre_save.x = form.cleaned_data['x']
    letter_picture_pre_save.y = form.cleaned_data['y']
    letter_picture_pre_save.w = form.cleaned_data['w']
    letter_picture_pre_save.h = form.cleaned_data['h']
    letter_picture_pre_save.save()
```